# Apache2 Linux Mint URL without trailing slash not working for HTTP to HTTPS redirect/rewrite

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, linux-mint, ssl, https

I set up an Apache2 server on Linux Mint. I configured the `default-ssl` site to use a SSL certificate that I bought and the default site works just fine with SSL.

However when I try to access a directory like `example.com/thing` it redirects me to `https://example.com:433/thing/` and gives me an unavailable website. If I go to `example.com/thing/` it redirects me to `https://example.com/thing/` and everything works fine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying the configs are attempting to send you to:

```
https://example.com:433/thing/
```

That seems weird since the standard `https` port is `443` and not `433`. Maybe that is the issue? Regardless I will attempt to assist with the trailing slash issue.

First, I am not 100% sure about how Linux Mint works, but if you have Apache2 installed this `a2enmod` command should work to enable [Apache `mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) which is needed for the tweaks you are going to make:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

If `mod_rewrite` is already enabled, then running that command won’t hurt; you’ll just get a message that `mod_rewrite` is enabled. Whatever the message is, move onto the actial rewrite rules.

So as far as the trailing slash goes, you can add this to your plain `http` config as well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

That `RewriteCond` basically says, “Catch any URLs that don’t have a trailing slash…” and the `RewriteRule` that follows it will actually repair the missing slash issue by rewriting the URL to have a slash.

Then add this to your plain `http` config—if you don’t have it in place already—to redirect non `https` traffic to your `https` site.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Now since you have not provided any examples of the Apache configs you are using, I am not 100% sure this stuff will just work “as is” but hopefully it can aid you and put you on the right path to solving this issue. And if it works verbatim/“as is”? Then great!

Comment: Sorry for not posting any configs, my bad. You led me on the right track. The actual problem was that I had defined a permanent redirect to port 433 but not 443. Now everything works as expected :D